# MATLAB: Automatic resizing of GUI components/fonts

Tags: matlab, user-interface, resize, screen-resolution

I am having problems in trying to make my MATLAB GUIs **automatically resizeable**. 
After exhaustively searching the web for help and lots of testing, I could not find out a solution.

I have been developing a simple GUI (with MATLAB, *without using GUIDE*) in my laptop (**Screen size/resolution = 1366x768**). A very simplified version looks like this:

### [image: GUI displayed in the laptop]

When I run the same GUI in my desktop computer (**Screen size/resolution = 1920x1080**), it shows in the following way:

### [image: GUI displayed in the desktop]

The dimensions of the GUI are automatically initialized taking into account the screensize (***the code is provided in the bottom of this post***). As you can see (highlighted by the red arrows), the fonts/spacing between components do not automatically resize so that the GUI has the same aspect no matter where we run the file.

Additionally, when the GUI is manually resized, some overlap of the components occurs:

### [image: GUI displayed in the desktop - After manual resizing]

---

The code used for this minimal working example is the following:

```
function resizingGUIexample()

%% SET UP GUI
hdl.mainfig = figure(); 

% MANAGE FIGURE DIMENSIONS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(hdl.mainfig, 'Units', 'pixels');
dims              = get(0, 'ScreenSize');
screenHeight      = dims(4);
verticalMargins   = floor((0.2*screenHeight)/2);          % =10% of the screen height in each side
figureHeight      =       (0.8*screenHeight);
figureWidth       =       (0.8*screenHeight)*(4/3);       % 4/3 Aspect Ratio
set(hdl.mainfig, 'Position', [0, verticalMargins, ... 
                figureWidth, figureHeight]);

movegui(hdl.mainfig,'center')     % move GUI to center

color = get(hdl.mainfig,'Color'); % get background color to hide static texts, etc...

% AXES ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hdl.axes = axes('Parent',   hdl.mainfig,  ...
             'Units',   'Normalized', ...
          'Position',   [0.295 0.05 0.63 0.63*(4/3)]);

% PUSH BUTTONS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hdl.donePB = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig,                          ...
                  'Position',   [0.85 0.91 0.075 0.075], ...
                    'String',   'Done',                  ...
                  'Fontsize',   16,                      ...
                     'Units',   'normalized',            ...
                'FontWeight',   'Bold');

% BUTTON GROUP and RADIO BUTTONS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hdl.buttonGroup = uibuttongroup('Parent',    hdl.mainfig,  ...
                          'FontSize',    16,           ...
                        'FontWeight',    'Bold',       ...
                   'BackgroundColor',    color,        ...
                             'Units',    'Normalized', ... 
                          'Position',    [0.05 0.69 0.2 0.2]);
titleBG = sprintf('Intensity\nNormalization');
set(hdl.buttonGroup, 'Title', titleBG);

hdl.VolumeRB = uicontrol(hdl.buttonGroup,                   ...
                             'Style',    'radiobutton', ...
                            'String',    'Volume',      ...
                          'FontSize',    14,            ...
                        'FontWeight',    'Bold',        ...
                             'Units',    'normalized',  ...
                   'BackgroundColor',    color,         ...
                          'Position',    [0.1 0.67 0.8 0.3]);

hdl.SliceRB = uicontrol(hdl.buttonGroup,                   ...
                            'Style',    'radiobutton', ...
                           'String',    'Slice',       ...
                         'FontSize',    14,            ...
                       'FontWeight',    'Bold',        ...
                            'Units',    'normalized',  ...
                  'BackgroundColor',    color,         ...
                         'Position',    [0.1 .25 0.8 0.3]);

end
```

Any ideas of how I can solve these issues?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards,

Fábio Nery

**EDIT1:** I am also extremely open to suggestions for better ways to initialize the GUI dimensions and strategies for avoiding problems when running GUIs in different monitors/screen resolutions.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, well done for not using GUIDE - you have passed the first test :)

I strongly recommend that you take a look at, and use, Ben Tordoff's [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox). Although you can do this sort of thing using the `ResizeFcn` property, I can tell you that it's *far* easier with GUI Layout Toolbox, which just takes care of that stuff for you.

Managing a GUI that may be run on different (maybe multiple) monitors at different sizes and resolutions is a pain. I'd recommend specifying up front a range of sizes/resolutions that you're going to support, and sticking to that (even erroring if the application finds itself on an unsupported setup), rather than trying to be fully general. If you have to make everything work even on a lowest common denominator setup, you may have to sacrifice ease of us on a more normal setup.

You seem to have discovered `get(0, 'ScreenSize')` and the `movegui` command. Other useful things which come to mind are `get(0, 'MonitorPositions')`, `get(0, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch')`, and using the `OuterPosition` rather than `Position` property of figures.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *ResizeFcn* command? You can use this to have MATLAB automatically resize your radiobuttons, panels, etc. to whatever size you need. You could use this function to make the size of your buttons and panels a function of the GUI dimesnions.

There is plenty of documenetation online on how to use it. For example, this explains how to use it for a uipanel: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-panel-containers-in-figures--uipanels.html#f7-53231

You can also type:

> > edit  ([docroot '/techdoc/creating_plots/examples/doc_uipanel1']);

into your command window to launch an example gui in which they use the resize function to resize various objects within the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a `uipanel` as the parent of a `uicontrol` is one way to make MATLAB GUI font sizes independent of screen resolution. You would need to set `fontunits` as `normalized` prior to setting the `fontsize`. Also set the `fontsize` to a fractional value between 0 and 1.

An example code is as follows.

```
hp = uipanel(...);
uicontrol(hp,'text','fontunits','normalized','fontsize',0.5,...);
```

The caveat of this approach is that the `fontsize` will scale with the parent object, which likely scales with your application window. In my applications, this behavior has been desirable.

Answer (score 0):

you can to use:

```
function yourfunction
scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');%Obtem o tamanho do monitor

hFigure = figure(...  %Insere Uma figura para construção da interface
    'NumberTitle','off',...
    'Menubar','none',...
    'Tag','Figure',...
    'Name','You Figure',...
    'Units','pixels',...
    'Resize','on',...
    'Position',[(scrsz(3)-300)/2 (scrsz(4)-600)/2 800 700]);

Button = uicontrol('parent',hFigure,...%Insere objeto do tipo Pushbutton!
    'Style','pushbutton',...
    'String','Processa',...
    'Units','normalized',... 
    'Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5],...
    'Callback',{@callbackButton}); 

function callbackButton(hObject,eventdata)
a = 1
```